# How to remove baidu / hao123 from internet explorer

Tags: windows-8, internet-explorer

I have tried to set Internet options to http://www.yahoo.com.sg/
And have gone to Internet options manage add-ons to remove baidu etc.

Still whenever I open my internet explorer, it redirects me to this website: http://www.hao123.com/?tn=97473572_hao_pg

How do I remove it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get rid of malicious spyware, malware, viruses or rootkits from my PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-do-i-get-rid-of-malicious-spyware-malware-viruses-or-rootkits-from-my-pc)

Answer (score 0):

If you have this, there is spyware on your computer. Scan your pc with spyware, remove everything, and try again. It is possible there is additional software installed that actively changes your homepage. Look for these in your `Programs and Features` option in `Control Panel`. It is a good idea to sort in date and look for the date this started to happen.

Comment: I tried but I could not find hao 123 in the control panel

Comment: I also tried using windows defender but the ms windows defender says that there are no malware or spyware detected. Definitions as at 9 August 2014.

Comment: Try searching with Hitman Pro and Malwarebytes Anti Malware.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use ADWcleaner tool.

https://toolslib.net/downloads/viewdownload/1-adwcleaner/

Comment: I tried but it does not work

Comment: I also use windows defender but the ms windows defender says that there are no malware or spyware detected. Definitions as at 9 August 2014.

Answer (score 0):

#### What didn't work

I also tried ADWcleaner, Spybot S&D but neither scanner/cleaner worked for HAO123.  It infected both my IE and Firefox (but didn't affected my Chrome).

#### What Worked

Eventually I used YAC to scan and clean and after a reboot, it fixed the HAO123 redirect problem.  Hope this helps!